# jade block contain only raw text

Tags: block, pug

I would like to have a jade block for my title, e.g.

```
html
  head
    title
      block head_title
```

And then mypage.jade

```
block head_title.
  raw text here
```

But jade seems to always expect a tag within a block, and outputs

```
<raw>text here</raw>
```

Comment: how about `p raw text here`. will output `<p>raw text here</p>`

Comment: yeah but a <p> inside of <head><title> is not ideal...

Comment: ah ... forgot that the result will go into the title. did you try hunterloftis' solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pipe:

```
block head_title
  | raw text here
```

docs: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-3

Comment: awesome thanks! It would be nice to be able to do multiline w/o the pipes (using ".") but it doesn't look like that's supported atm.

Comment: Yeah that's interesting; I guess you can use a trailing period for regular tags (eg, I know that `p.` works), but not for named blocks.